# Untitled document (Pdf) opened in whatsApp version of IOS (Tyntec)

Tags: c#, iphone, asp.net-core-webapi, whatsapp

Iam using third part called tyntec to deal with whatsApp messages ,
my Api deals with tyntec to send a file  to specific number :-

and this is the part in my repository which has responsability to talk with tyntec :-

```
public async Task<SendingMessageRespons> SendRequestAsync(object requestBody)
        {
            var serializedRequest = "";
            try
            {
                serializedRequest = JsonSerializer.Serialize(requestBody, new JsonSerializerOptions
                {
                    PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
                    IgnoreNullValues = true
                });

                var requestContent = new StringContent(serializedRequest, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                var client = new HttpClient();

                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("apikey", _config.APIkey);

                var response = await client.PostAsync(_config.APIUrl, requestContent);

                var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var message = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Message>(content);

                    return SendingMessageRespons.Create(response.StatusCode, serializedRequest, content, message.messageId);
                }

                else
                {
                    return SendingMessageRespons.Create(response.StatusCode, serializedRequest, content, string.Empty);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return SendingMessageRespons.Create(HttpStatusCode.ExpectationFailed, serializedRequest, ex.Message, null);
            }

        }
```

and it's configuration:-

[image]

my problem is when I send the pdf to any android user ... it works fine and the name of pdf shows like this :-

[image]

but when I send the same pdf to IOS user the name becomes "Untitled" Like this
[image]

and when I open the pdf it's name shows
[image]

Am trying to guess where is the problem but I can't figure out

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer

the problem was in parameter of the body request :-
My old Json

```
{
 "to": "201119959346", 
 "channels": ["whatsapp"],
 
       
 "whatsapp": {
    "from" : "201000081092",
    "media" : {
      "type" : "document"
       ,
      "url" : "https://www.tyntec.com/sites/default/files/uploads/1608_tyntec_CorporateBackground.pdf",
      "caption" : "hady125 corporate background"
    },
    "contentType":"media"
 }
}
```

The new one :-

```
{
 "to": "201119959346", 
 "channels": ["whatsapp"],
 
       
 "whatsapp": {
    "from" : "201000081092",
    "media" : {
      "type" : "document"
       ,
       "filename":"hady corporate background" // the new param
       ,
      "url" : "https://www.tyntec.com/sites/default/files/uploads/1608_tyntec_CorporateBackground.pdf",
      "caption" : "hady125 corporate background"
    },
    "contentType":"media"
 }
}

notice :- you should keep the two params Caption and filename to work in IOS and Android
```